# Getting DriverServiceNotFoundException even specifying correct path

Tags: vb.net, selenium-chromedriver

I have VB.net code that utilizes Selenium and the Chrome driver to navigate to a page and download a file.  It works fine with and without headless options specified. But I want to suppress the command window also.  Based on what I read, I need to launch the ChromeDriver specifying 'true' for the HideCommandPromptWindow property.  When I do this, I get this error:

OpenQA.Selenium.DriverServiceNotFoundException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=The file False\chromedriver.exe does not exist. The driver can be downloaded at http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
  Source=WebDriver
  StackTrace:
   at OpenQA.Selenium.DriverService..ctor(String servicePath, Int32 port, String driverServiceExecutableName, Uri driverServiceDownloadUrl)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriverService..ctor(String executablePath, String executableFileName, Int32 port)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver..ctor(String chromeDriverDirectory, ChromeOptions options)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver..ctor(String chromeDriverDirectory)

I'm using the path that appears in the TitleBar of the CommandWindow I see when it runs and works, so I know the path and file are valid.

Based on the fact that the error Message of 'The file False\chromedrive.exe does not exist...' it seems that the arg I'm passing for the path is somehow evaluating as 'False'.

This is a snippet of the code being run - it errors at line 219 or 220:

```
    Dim cOpt As New ChromeOptions()
    cOpt.AddArguments("--headless", "--no-sandbox", "--disable-gpu")

    Dim param As New Dictionary(Of String, Object)
    param.Add("behavior", "allow")
    param.Add("downloadPath", G.gRadiusExportsFolder)

    Dim cdp As String = FixPathSlash(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath, False)

    Dim d As New ChromeDriver(cOpt)
    'LINE 219-- Dim d As New ChromeDriver(ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(cdp, "chromedriver.exe").HideCommandPromptWindow = True)
    'LINE220-- Dim d As New ChromeDriver(ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(cdp, "chromedriver.exe").HideCommandPromptWindow = True, cOpt)

    Wait(5)
    d.ExecuteChromeCommand("Page.setDownloadBehavior", param)
```

Comment: And where is the path to the driver?

Comment: D:\Steve.Strong\MathnasiumRelatedVisualStudioProjects\GetRAD\GetRAD\bin\Debug

Comment: I mean where in your code.

Comment: Just to be clear, the uncommented code (what would be line 218) works fine.  It's only when I try CreateDefaultService that it errors out.  The variable cdp is the path to the driver that I pass.  It's set to "My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath" which is where I have the driver.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Dim cOpt As New ChromeOptions()
    cOpt.AddArguments("--headless", "--no-sandbox", "--disable-gpu")

    Dim param As New Dictionary(Of String, Object)
    param.Add("behavior", "allow")
    param.Add("downloadPath", G.gRadiusExportsFolder)

    Dim driverService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService()
    driverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = True
    Dim d As New ChromeDriver(driverService, cOpt)

    Wait(5)
    d.ExecuteChromeCommand("Page.setDownloadBehavior", param)
```

Comment: Made a few changes - creating driverService - then setting the HideCommandPromptWindow property to True.  It now runs completely silent.